# Unable to get Response from API in angular

Tags: javascript, java, angular, angularjs

I have created a Rest API in Java with the request Mapping(/value/generate).

```
System.out.println(value);
        
        
        if(!value.equals(null)){
         return new ResponseEntity(value, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            
    }
```

Value is getting printed in Console when iam call this through postman.

But i need to print this value in my Angular console.

Below is code i have created in angular.

service.ts

```
generatevalue(): Observable<String> {
return this.http.get('https://localhost:8080/value/generate')
```

Component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.service.generatevalue().subscribe((Response) => {
      console.log(Response)
     
  }
 }
```

Please let me know where i went wrong.

Comment: What do you see in your console?

Comment: What does Observable<any> instead of Observable<String> give you?

Comment: You'll want to use `http` for `localhost`. Angular should still be smart enough to run it successfully nonetheless, but just a tip. Other than that, this could be related to CORS (an issue Postman would not run into). But as others have mentioned, check your console first and see what the actual API response is.

Comment: @Enrico It won't change anything since changing TypeScript types won't change the runtime javascript code.

Comment: @enrico Iam getting the desried value.Basicaly the value is nothing but token value.So iam getting that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url should probably be "**http://localhost:8080/value/generate**". Did you check your console for errors? It should print an error 404 somewhere.

Comment: Thats Typo error @yochyo.I have edit now

Comment: It should probably be http instead of https. For https, you would need a certificate. Can you update your question with the error message you get?

Comment: iam not getting any error i just want to print the response in angular console

Comment: Try replacing your js code with this this.service.generatevalue().subscribe((Response) => { console.log(Response)}, error =>console.error(error)) it should print an error now

Comment: You saved my day Yochyo..!! That error log helped me to find my mistake.Now its working..thanks a lot man..~~